# How to extend Dockerimages via docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i try to extend my Basic Images from Webdevops.
I'll try to add the base-app to my Container that already exists.

Thats my docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  base-app:
    image: "webdevops/base-app"
    restart: always
  apache:
    image: "webdevops/php-apache-dev:7.2"
    container_name: apache
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - base-app
    volumes:
      - "./:/app"

    environment:
      - XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug
      - XDEBUG_CLIENT_HOST=host.docker.internal
      - XDEBUG_CLIENT_PORT=9003 # 9000=xdebug v2, 9003=v3
      - XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK=0
      - XDEBUG_REMOTE_AUTOSTART=1
      - XDEBUG_IDE_KEY=docker
      - XDEBUG_START_WITH_REQUEST=trigger
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
  mysql:
    image: "mysql:latest"
    restart: always
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - './mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    depends_on:
      - base-app
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'xxxxx'
```

How to extend my Images with base-app?

Comment: Docker-compose is used to run images. If you want to extend an image, you create a Dockerfile and use `docker build`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend any image using a Dockerfile.  For example, you might write a Dockerfile

```bash
FROM webdevops/php-apache-dev:7.2
COPY . /app
```

You can do other steps as required, like `RUN`ning an installation command or setting an alternate `CMD` you need this image to run.  You generally should avoid putting host names or credentials of any sort into the Docker image, leave these as `environment:` settings in the Compose file.

In your `docker-compose.yml` file, use a `build:` block to indicate this image should be built.  Do *not* include an `image:` line; unless you're specifically planning to push this extended image to a registry; and if you do it must have a *different* name from the base image.

```yaml
services:
  apache:
    build: . # _instead of_ image:
    restart: always
    depends_on: [...]
    ports: [...]
    environment: [...]
    # no volumes: since the code is already in the image
    # container_name: is usually unnecessary
```